# Kubernetes, AWS : Service creating extra Security-Group per service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am working on Kubernetes where our pods are running on AWS. I am creating a service with pre-defined LoadBalancer specifications. Still, Kubernetes is adding an extra SG to the loadbalancer. How can I specify not to do that? Thank you.

service.yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: akeneo-service
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: akeneo-service-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/component: backend
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
  annotations:
      # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "ssl"
       # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: OUR_ARN
       # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: "sg-0d3a65fc39e47e3cf"
  name: akeneo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: akeneo-service
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Any help would be nice. :-)

Comment: Do you mean the LB will be created with unwanted `sg-0d3a65fc39e47e3cf`? Have you tried to remove `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups` from annotations in metadata?

Comment: @Rahman : No, that's the correct SG. I only want to use that SG, and no other SG's for that loadbalancer. Kubernetes somehow is creating a new SG per service and adding them to the loadbalancer.